# Playing audio after the page loads in html

Tags: html

I inserted the audio in html. But the audio gets started before the entire page loads. I want the audio to be played after the entire page gets loaded.

```
<audio src="bg.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></audio>
```

Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 30):

You're going to need JavaScript for that. Remove the `autoplay` attribute:

```
<audio id="my_audio" src="bg.mp3" loop="loop"></audio>
```

and add a script like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
}
```

Or if you use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_audio").get(0).play();
});
```

Comment: Got this error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`. When I manually execute `play()` in the console, it works fine.

Comment: my solution is adding 5 second delay, does anyone have better solution for `DOMException` error?

Comment: @thdoan have you fixed Dom exception issue ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 10):

Just Copy and Paste this Code in Body section of your HTML Code.

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

and make sure that your audio file should be in same folder.

Comment: what if the audio file is elsewhere? How to do it then?

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker You are getting this cause the browser is blocking the auto play.

You can find more in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#Autoplay_and_autoplay_blocking

Answer (score 3):

I think you must use JS (jQuery) function to do get document ready

> $(document).ready(function()

[Play an audio file using jQuery when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489710/how-can-i-play-sound-in-jquery-when-click-a-button)

You have answer here (if I follow you right)

Answer (score 1):

If the audio file is somewhere else in your local storage, you might be able to create a node application that creates a duplicate of the audio file you are interested in playing and puts it in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

For a repeated tone place the below code

```
        <audio src="./audio/preloader.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></audio>
```

and for a single time, remove the loop. Then it should be like this

```
        <audio src="./audio/preloader.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
```