# Play audio and control start/stop by JSF app

Tags: jsf, audio

I'm seeking for a solution how could I control playing the audio file from the JSF app.
I don't need the complete solution, just a reference to a component I could use to control playing the audio file (start/stop/change the sound).

I've tried to search in the past questions, but without a success.

My setup is based on Java EE 5, a migration to Java EE 6 might be the option too if really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you use J2EE6 maybe you can try primefaces and the component "Multimedia", but this component depends sometimes of external plugins (flash, windows media, etc), but it's an option.

[PrimeFaces - Multimedia](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml)

Or if you can't use Primefaces, maybe you can try doing a different approach using JQuery and HTML.

[JQuery - HTML5 audio controls](http://codesamplez.com/programming/control-html5-audio-with-jquery)

[Java Script - play audio with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489710/play-an-audio-file-using-jquery-when-a-button-is-clicked)

I hope, this help you. Good Luck.