# phpBB3 add sound on button click

Tags: html, phpbb3

for a Halloween special I'd like to add spooky sounds when pressing "Post Reply", "New Topic" or even when clicking on smilies.

However I don't know how and where phpBB handles button clicks. Is it even possible?

One problem I can imagine is that the sounds starts playing after the click but stops as soon as the new page is loaded. I had that problem when adding global music to a style inside overall_header.html

I use phpBB 3.0.12

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** How and where phpBB handles button clicks depends on your style. Upload  jquery.js on your server. Edit your overall_header or overall_footer to add the jquery.min.js file to your javascript librairies. Ensure that your button has an id and now you can handle button clicks.

To do that try to have a look to : [Play an audio file using jQuery when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489710/play-an-audio-file-using-jquery-when-a-button-is-clicked)

**Step 2:** In your onload event, remove the href attribute of the button, now when you click on your button, only music is playing.

**Step 3:** edit your onclick event, after playing music or after some second, redirect to the post.php page