# play sound by click js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with playing music. It doesnt play. I want to play music by clicking on the button.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').submit(function() {
      var audio = document.getElementById('audioFile');
      audio.play();
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <audio id="audioFile">
    <source src="font/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <div class="inputMessage">

    <form method="POST" action="/index.php">
      <textarea class="chatMessage" name="text" placeholder="Текст сообщения"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="enter" value="Отправить">
      <input type="reset" value="Очистить">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try with this solution  :http://stackoverflow.com/a/18628124/2815635

Comment: What error message do you see? What does debugging show?

Comment: I need to send text from textarea and when I click on the buttom, I should hear a sound

Comment: `document.getElementById('audioFile');`  does not point to `src` attribute in `soruce` tag.  Try to change the reference. And when you have jquery , why using JavaScript code to get the element attributes ??

Comment: I really dont know how to debug, but in log i can see nothing

Comment: i was trying do it like this: $('.button').click(function()  
                  {
                   var audio = new Audio();
                   audio.src("font/sound.mp3");
                   audio.autoplay();
                   
                  });

Comment: check this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489710/play-an-audio-file-using-jquery-when-a-button-is-clicked``.

Comment: Why the downvote? Because they used the php tag?

Comment: @Bulrush don't ask. Everything seems to get randomly downvoted all the time.

Comment: I've put a php tag, because in my code in the top side of the file i have php code for work with POST  method. I've removed that part of code, but forgot to remove php tag :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489710/play-an-audio-file-using-jquery-when-a-button-is-clicked i'm trying to fix it with this prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: `.submit()` method exists on forms, not inputs. You can use `.click()` method instead.
Second thing: when you click your button the form is sent and page redirects to /index.php. To make playing sound possible you have to stay at the same page (request can still be send asynchronously). Here is the way to prevent loading new page:

```
$('.button').click(function(ev) { // jQuery passes the event as a parameter
  var audio = document.getElementById('audioFile');
  audio.play();
  ev.preventDefault(); // and we prevent the form from being sent
});
```

Take a look at demo: https://jsfiddle.net/s48jcrvc/1/

Comment: it works, but now i have another problem:when I click button, song starts to play, but when I click button again, it won't send a form until song is playing. How to fix it? When I press button, song should be started from beginning

Comment: Set `audio.currentTime = 0;` before playing. And please accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: And the last question is how to play music again if it has finished?

Comment: I've just find an answer : I should put `audio.loop=true;` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Good to hear that!

Comment: Excuse me , but now I have another problem - the text from textarea isn't sended to global array $_POST by clicking buttom :(

Comment: As i said - the request should be done asynchronously, search for "ajax requests". Ask new question if needed.

Comment: please, check out my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753853/send-data-to-post-array-via-ajax