# send data to $_POST array via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I start to play music via button 'submit', and as a result my form is not sent to global array $_POST. How to do that?  Should I use AJAX?  How?
Music plays, but form isn't sent :(

```
 <?php

    include_once 'connect.php';



if($_POST['text']){ 
    mysqli_query($CONNECT,"TRUNCATE TABLE user");
        $query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('','$_POST[text]')";
        mysqli_query($CONNECT, $query);
}
  ?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <title>Input</title>
                <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

                <script>
                 $(document).ready(function() {
                   $('.button').click(function(event) {
                     $('.chatMessage').val('');
                     var audio = document.getElementById('audioFile');
                     audio.currentTime = 0;
                     audio.play();
                     audio.loop = true;
                     event.preventDefault();
                   });               
                 });
             $("#form").submit(function(event){
                 var $form = $(this);
                 var $inputs = $form.find("input, button, textarea");
                 var serializedData = $form.serialize();
                 $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
                 $.ajax({
                    url: "/index.php",
                   type: "post",
                   data: serializedData
                });
                });
               </script>
               </head>

               <body>
                 <audio id="audioFile">
                   <source src="font/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                 </audio>
                 <div class="inputMessage">

                   <form id="form" method="POST" action="/index.php">
                     <textarea class="chatMessage" name="text" placeholder="Текст сообщения"></textarea>
                     <br>
                     <input class="button" type="submit" name="enter" value="Отправить">
                     <input type="reset" value="Очистить">
                   </form>
                 </div>
               </body>
        </html>
```

I need your answers, please!

Comment: Should you help me with code? I don't know, how to send it to array

Comment: You need to first go learn how to submit data with ajax. [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is one good tool. Come back to stackoverflow after you've done research, have made a solid attempt, and have a specific question.

Comment: I'm trying this, but it plays music, but doesn't send form: `$("#form").submit(function(event){
                 var $form = $(this);
                 var $inputs = $form.find("input, button, textarea");
                 var serializedData = $form.serialize();
                 $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
                 $.ajax({
                    url: "/index.php",
                   type: "post",
                   data: serializedData
                });
                });
               </script>`

Comment: You are referencing to your form by ID, but there is not ID set.

Comment: check out now my code :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems with this. First, you are overriding the click handler for your button.  If you also want it to also post the form, you should `return true;` at the end of your handler.

Also, you will find that the browser will reload the page when that happens, so there is no real reason you would want to play music. Instead you should add some PHP to add  JavaScript that plays the music when you correctly receive the post data.

Alternatively, you could send the data with AJAX within your click handler, as @jszobody suggests.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```